# Rolling up the website header with the scrolling from a certain point down

Tags: jquery, css, header, web, vertical-scrolling

I wanted my website header to:

i.) stay fixed on the top while the user's scroll position is on the top (let's say: on the top 300px, or ideally until the scrolling has not reached the next element down)

ii.) and when it reaches a certain point while being being scrolled down, the header would change to absolute positioning, creating a "rolling up" effect while the page is scrolled down further.

I have got this working with the following code, BUT when i test this on my ipad, it is very slow, the header has several seconds delays before reacting. **Is there a better practice, perhaps a more efficient way to achieve this effect?**

```
<div class="header">
</div>
<div class="scrollarea1">
</div>
<div class="scrollarea2">
</div>


.header {
    background: #282828;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}
.scrollarea1 {
    background: #EFEFEF;
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
}
.scrollarea2 {
    background: #C0C0C0;
    height: 1700px;
    width: 100%;
}


$(document).ready(function () {
var elementStyle=document.getElementsByClassName("header").item(0).style;
        $(window).scroll(function(){             
                if( $(window).scrollTop() >= 300 ) {
                        elementStyle.position = "absolute";
                        elementStyle.marginTop = "300px";
                } else {
                        elementStyle.position = "fixed";
                        elementStyle.marginTop = "0px";
                }
        });
});
```

JsFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/79ugd4x9/15/

Comment: Don't use an iPad :p

Comment: Or don't use websites just print stuff on paper.. Do you have a workable solution as well???

Comment: Have you tested it on any other hand held devices?  It may be specific to Safari on iOS devices.  There's not enough info here to help.

Comment: This helped me to achieve better scroll performance on all devices when the DOM becomes busy: http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/

Answer (score 1):

The following will only work on iOS devices, it will not work in most desktop browsers. You should keep around your scroll event handler if you need to support other browsers.

You can try using `position: sticky` and the `touchmove` event. I'm also using `pageYOffset` instead of `scrollTop()` as on iOS `scrollTop()` is not updated until the scroll event finishes.

```
var elementStyle = document.getElementsByClassName("header").item(0).style;
$(window).on('touchstart touchmove touchend', function () {
    if (window.pageYOffset >= 300) {
        elementStyle.position = "fixed";
        elementStyle['-webkit-transform'] = "translate3D(0px," + -(window.pageYOffset - 300) + "px,0px)";
    } else {
        elementStyle.position = "sticky";
        elementStyle['-webkit-transform'] = "translate3D(0px,0px,0px)";
    }
})
```

Animation:

```
.header {
    ...
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms linear;
    transition: all 500ms linear
}
```

You might want to consider using `translate3D` instead of changing `margin-top` as it can be hardware accelerated. The animation should work, but I can only test in an emulator with a limited refresh rate so I can't confirm.

<kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r4ufr872/show/)</kbd> <kbd>[Edit](http://jsfiddle.net/r4ufr872/)</kbd>

**Edit:** To get this working with inertial scrolling, call the handler in both the touch events and the scroll events. On iOS, the scroll handler is fired as the scroll event finishes.